# How to redirect to another page onclicking on button in gridview along with parameters

Tags: .net, vb.net, gridview

I have button in one of the columns in a gridview. On clicking on a button I need to redirect to another page along with parameters to another page.

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a `Server.Transfer(url, true)` to the button click event in the codebehind.

Comment: in the codebehind i have no event for this button as i have added it in the Gridview as ItemTemplate

Comment: try using RowCommand of GridView http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/web/ui/webcontrols/GridViewClassRowCommand.aspx