# How to redirect to another page on clicking on button in gridview

Tags: vb.net

Duplicate of [How to redirect to another page onclicking on button in gridview along with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645499/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-onclicking-on-button-in-gridview-along-with-param)

hi guys,
       I  have a gridview with button in one column.I want to redirect to another page along with parameters on clicking on button.Is there any option to do this in rowdatabound event in gridview.If there is any other option can anybody help

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be a button that does the redirecting, you have to capture the RowCommand event, and from there on you can redirect using the options you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean in Silverlight? If so you can use the `HtmlPage.Window.Navigate` method.